# Imposible to connect from Docker IIS with PHP to SQL Server

Tags: php, sql-server, docker, iis

I've several days trying to run a docker container from [IIS image](https://github.com/microsoft/iis-docker/blob/master/samples/php/Dockerfile) and PHP and i don't get it.

The objective is to connect to existing external Microsoft SQL Server 2000.

I tried all PHP versions, from 5.6 to 7.4 and their respective Visual Studio Code libraries and PHP ODBC extensions but doesn't work.

I have ping from inside cotainer to the database.

The last try was:

[PHP 5.6.9](https://windows.php.net/downloads/releases/archives/php-5.6.38-nts-Win32-VC11-x86.zip)

[VIsual Studio Code 11 (2012)](https://download.microsoft.com/download/1/6/B/16B06F60-3B20-4FF2-B699-5E9B7962F9AE/VSU_4/vcredist_x86.exe)

- on iis:

```
C:\php\ext\php_sqlsrv_7_nts_x86.dll
C:\php\ext\php_pdo_sqlsrv_7_nts_x86.dll
```

- php.ini file:

```
extension=php_pdo_odbc.dll
extension=php_odbc.dll
```

- prueba.php file:

```
$connection_string = "Driver={SQL Server};Server=$server;Database=$database;";
$conn = odbc_connect($connection_string,$user,$pass);
var_dump($conn);
```

but the error is:

```
'08001','[08001][Microsoft][ODBC SQL Server Driver][DBNETLIB]SQL Server does not exist or access denied.
```

- Dockerfile:

```
# escape=`

#
# This Dockerfile is provided for demonstration purposes only and it is not supported by Microsoft
# PHP 7.1 x64 running on IIS
#

FROM mcr.microsoft.com/windows/servercore/iis AS php71

SHELL ["powershell", "-Command", "$ErrorActionPreference = 'Stop';"]

RUN `
    try { `
        # Install PHP 71`
        #Invoke-WebRequest 'https://sourceforge.net/projects/phpinstallermsi/files/zip/php-7.1.7-nts-Win32-VC14-x64.zip/download' -UserAgent '' -OutFile C:\php.zip; `
        #Expand-Archive -Path c:\php.zip -DestinationPath C:\PHP; `
        `
        # Install PHP 569`
        Invoke-WebRequest 'https://windows.php.net/downloads/releases/archives/php-5.6.38-nts-Win32-VC11-x86.zip' -UserAgent 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/78.0.3904.87 Safari/537.36' -OutFile C:\php.zip; `
        Expand-Archive -Path c:\php.zip -DestinationPath C:\PHP; `
        `
        # Install Visual Studio Code 11 (2012)`
        Invoke-WebRequest 'https://download.microsoft.com/download/1/6/B/16B06F60-3B20-4FF2-B699-5E9B7962F9AE/VSU_4/vcredist_x86.exe' -UserAgent '' -OutFile C:\vc_redist-x64.exe; `
        `
        # Install Visual Studio Code 14 (2015)`
        #Invoke-WebRequest 'https://download.microsoft.com/download/6/A/A/6AA4EDFF-645B-48C5-81CC-ED5963AEAD48/vc_redist.x64.exe' -UserAgent '' -OutFile C:\vc_redist-x64.exe; `
        `
    } `
    catch { `
        $_.Exception; `
        $_; `
        exit 1; `
    }

ADD php.ini-development 'C:\PHP\php.ini'

FROM microsoft/iis

COPY --from=php71 ["/php/", "/php/"]
COPY --from=php71 ["/vc_redist-x64.exe", "/vc_redist-x64.exe"]

#
# Enable required IIS Features
# Install VC Redist 14
# Configure IIS
# Configure system PATH
#
RUN dism.exe /Online /Enable-Feature /FeatureName:IIS-CGI /All && `
    C:\vc_redist-x64.exe /quiet /install && `
    #del C:\vc_redist-x64.exe && `
    %windir%\system32\inetsrv\appcmd.exe set config /section:system.webServer/fastCgi /+[fullPath='c:\PHP\php-cgi.exe'] && `
    %windir%\system32\inetsrv\appcmd.exe set config /section:system.webServer/handlers /+[name='PHP_via_FastCGI',path='*.php',verb='*',modules='FastCgiModule',scriptProcessor='c:\PHP\php-cgi.exe',resourceType='Either'] && `
    %windir%\system32\inetsrv\appcmd.exe set config -section:system.webServer/fastCgi /[fullPath='c:\PHP\php-cgi.exe'].instanceMaxRequests:10000 && `
    %windir%\system32\inetsrv\appcmd.exe set config -section:system.webServer/fastCgi /+[fullPath='c:\PHP\php-cgi.exe'].environmentVariables.[name='PHP_FCGI_MAX_REQUESTS',value='10000'] && `
    %windir%\system32\inetsrv\appcmd.exe set config -section:system.webServer/fastCgi /+[fullPath='c:\PHP\php-cgi.exe'].environmentVariables.[name='PHPRC',value='C:\PHP'] && `
    %windir%\system32\inetsrv\appcmd.exe set config /section:defaultDocument /enabled:true /+files.[value='index.php'] && `
    setx PATH /M %PATH%;C:\PHP && `
    setx PHP /M "C:\PHP" && `
    del C:\inetpub\wwwroot\* /Q

# Optional: Add a starter page
RUN powershell.exe -Command "'<?php phpinfo(); ?>' | Out-File C:\inetpub\wwwroot\info.php -Encoding UTF8"

# ADD any application content and perform any configuration below
ADD prueba.php 'C:\inetpub\wwwroot\prueba.php'
```

Anybody could help me please.

Comment: *"The objective is to connect to existing external Microsoft SQL Server 2000."* Why are you still using SQL Server 2000? That has been completely unsupported for almost a decade. It's long beyond the time to upgrade.

Comment: The database update it's not an option, it's a client requirement.

Comment: It's a client requirement to have a high security vulnerabilities?

Comment: You're right but you don't have to convince me. I have told the client several times that he should update the database

Comment: You can't ping a database, you ping servers. Using the ICMP protocol. Assuming the SQL Server is the default instance on the default port, have you allowed outbound tcp/1433 connections from the container?

Comment: To be honest, I wouldn't be surprised if the new SQL Server PHP Drivers **don't** support such an old version. Why *would* Microsoft create a new product in 2016/2017 that ensures compatibility for a product they hadn't supported since 2010?

Comment: If your SQL server lives at 192.168.1.2 you'd probably want to use `$server = 'tcp:192.168.1.2,1433'` to force tcp connections with the correct protocol and on the correct port.

Comment: Yes, ping to server: nmap -p 1433 host. The databse is used by other applications, so the database server port 1433 is opened, im going to check outbound tcp/1433 connections from the container. Thank you @AlwaysLearning